# Revisiting our close procedure and close reasons

Tags: support, close-reasons, closing-questions

In a comment in one of our [Meta discussions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5572/reducing-user-frustration) Aarthi [announced](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5572/reducing-user-frustration#comment14036_5572) a set of changes to the closing procedure:

> This is currently in spec-stage so I don't have lots of details available, but suffice it to say: how we handle closures/question rehab is going to be revisited in the next year, and the methodology of communicating this to the end user is expected to receive a complete makeover.

What changes have already been announced and how can I be part of the discussion for future changes?

Answer (score 6):

All the changes are now live, you can find more details on [MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-the-loop-the-closing-overhaul-is-live)

---

The first step was the brand new [about page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux) (see our [about page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about)), and the next one was the [changes in how duplicates work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/help-us-make-off-topic-close-reasons-clearer-to-the-op). Right now Stack Exchange is looking for feedback on revamping the close reasons, on the main Meta.

I will be updating this answer as more changes and requests for feedback are announced:

- [We're rolling out a new “Quick Start” guide to help new users learn the basics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/were-rolling-out-a-new-quick-start-guide-to-help-new-users-learn-the-basics) ✓
- [Changes to “close as duplicate” (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux) ✓
- [Help us make “Off-Topic” close reasons clearer to the OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/help-us-make-off-topic-close-reasons-clearer-to-the-op) ✓
- [Help us make “Not Constructive” and “Not a Real Question” closures more effective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv) ✓
- [Every “close” has its thorn: help us improve closing verbiage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-help-us-improve-closing-verbiage) ✓

Comment: Since there are per-site close messages coming up, when and how can we as a community go about giving input/suggestions for the close messages P.SE will get? (Should I ask this in a separate meta Q?)

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Let's wait until the feature is build and pushed to production first. I'm not 100% certain what kind of control we'll have over the per site close messages and to what degree we'll be able to customize them.

Comment: A very nice set of close reasons - http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/179/what-should-our-list-of-close-reasons-look-like/180#180