# Why is this question wrong? (asking for the name of a specific practice)

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

I was told to make a post here to understand why is my question wrong after it was placed on hold: [How is it called when you define constants that simply refer to a large namespace?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/218986/13833)

---

### Context

The question asks, essentially, how is it called when you create constants that refer to large namespaces in an attempt to simplify the writing. Basically, something like:

```
Sprite = Super::Large:Namespace::Graphics::Sprite
```

---

### Closing reason

The reason, it seems, is that my question is a [guessing game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) (at least that's the most upvoted reason).

---

### My reasoning

According to the [the linked blog post regarding guessing games](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), such questions involve vague, broad descriptions. However, I don't think that my question is vague at all. I am describing, very accurately, every step involved in the practice (which is to create constantes referring to large namespaces). I know perfectly well every aspect of the practice, but I don't know how is it called, which is what I'm asking.

### Examples

- [What is this (anti?)pattern called? (or how to describe it)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/207597/13833). The asker accurately describes an (anti)pattern, and wants to know how is it called:

> I don't have a practical problem to solve here; it's just bugging me
>   that there seems to be a common design element that I can't put a name
>   to.

- [Vocabulary: Should I call this apply or map?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171430/vocabulary-should-i-call-this-apply-or-map). The asker has a construct design, but is not sure whether it is a map or an apply method.

> Would you call this specific construct a [...] or would it better be
>   [...]

- [What it is a data structure of a certain type called?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/109400/what-it-is-a-data-structure-of-a-certain-type-called). He's creating a data structure and doesn't know how is it called.

> What is this called?

- [How do you call the process of taking a part of a function and making an individual function of it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155330/how-do-you-call-the-process-of-taking-a-part-of-a-function-and-making-an-individ). The asker describes a process and wants to know its technical term.

> I know there was a technical term for this. I'm just can't remember
>   what it was.

- [Is there a name for being able to quickly find the relevant code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/195426/13833). The asker is describing some sort of "ability to find relevant code", but he doesn't know how it is called, so he made the question:

> It's obviously part of maintainability, but is there a name for this
>   specific, desirable, property?

---

**How are all those open, upvoted questions different from mine? Why was mine closed exactly?**

They all accurately describe something, and they all want to know how is it called. I'm fairly certain that I am doing the same.

In fact, my question [happened to be answered](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/219004/13833). The answer was **Type Aliasing**.

Comment: You should start by giving your question a better (~more descriptive) title. "What is the name used for this kind of practice?" could be the title of all the other questions you referenced, that's not good.

Comment: @YannisRizos: You're right, I will fix that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I voted to reopen.  Personally, I don't think this particular question qualifies as a "guessing game" question.  From the [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/):

1. **Guessing game questions aren't practical.**  The answer helps you concisely communicate the intent of your module to other programmers, and helps research possibly better ways of doing type aliasing.  Those are both highly practical concerns.  You're not just asking out of curiosity.
2. **Guessing game questions don’t help others.**  While admittedly the gist of the question would be difficult to search, someone browsing the site can certainly learn something, and someone searching for "type aliasing" will get a good example of it.  Besides, the same people also whine that this site shouldn't allow questions that are too easy to google.  I guess they want some inscrutable precise medium level of googleability.
3. **Guessing game questions are unfair.**  The mere fact of the question being difficult to search means you aren't intentionally off-loading work on answerers.  Also, it's usually pretty easy to verify the consensus answer.  Even when it goes by multiple names, that's useful information.  If it happens to not have an "official name," that's also useful information.
4. **Guessing game questions aren’t educational.**  Knowing the term opens up a whole world of educational opportunities.  It allows you to do further research on best practices, and later when you move to a new language, it allows you to learn how to do the same thing.

The other common objection I see to this type of question is that it will encourage similar questions.  Well, duh.  That could be said of any topic.  We don't close architecture questions because that might make people ask too many architecture questions.  And it's not like you can make a series of questions out of this one by changing a couple words.

I understand some people don't personally like this kind of question.  That's why we let you hide certain tags.

Comment: what would you suggest us to do with low quality answers, "I call it _this_" / "I heard it called _that_"? Frankly, these are my only problem with naming game questions, particularly when answerers begin spreading this attitude to other kinds of questions. "- Why things are made that way? - Because such is life."

Comment: @gnat: You're telling us that your problem isn't the questions, but rather, the vague answers they get. Well then, you should punish the answers themselves, not the questions. Just because an acceptable question gets unacceptable answers doesn't mean we have to close the whole question. I understand the fear of a bad attitude spreading to other questions, but I'm fairly certain that getting rid of this kind of question is not the solution. I'd propose that if you see bad answers, report the bad answers. Why report the questions if they aren't bad by themselves?

Comment: @Omega can you tell me how exactly you suggest to "punish the answers"? And by the way you are right, questions don't get closed for just occasionally picking bad answers

Comment: @gnat: Flag them? I'm sure that if you flag them, something happens. I mean, it's like flagging something as "spam" or "low quality". I am not very experienced with SE, and am not sure what kind of penalty is given to spam/low-quality answers, but I guess that there is indeed a penalty? In which case, it seems reasonable to also penalise vague answers.

Comment: @Omega these flags are typically declined (I tested that) - one can't just stick "spam" or "low quality" and expect it to fly. If you're interested, refer here for more details: [Why are the moderators being so strict with quality related flags recently?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently)

Comment: @gnat: Ah, but then we got a problem that is not related to this topic. Because moderators being strict about flags doesn't seem like a good excuse to be closing acceptable questions.

Comment: @Omega no, it is directly related. I for one prefer to close questions that _attract_ low quality answers, just as a prevention of polluting site with these - and in my experience, naming games attract a lot of low quality answers. Closing does just that. If you know other way to deal with that, I would be happy to learn

Comment: @gnat: Well, in my case I prefer not to close questions if they aren't bad by themselves and instead deal with the bad answers, as they are the actual problem. But unfortunately, I have no influence over the moderating system's opinion regarding flags. It seems like it's settled that this kind of question will remain unaccepted in the community, but I'm afraid that it seems to be for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @gnat: Taking a step back, given that flags don't seem to be an option anymore, another possible punishment for the vague answers would be to simply downvote them. I take it that very downvoted answers appear invisible for newcomers, and also, downvotes will influence the answerers to stop doing vague answers. This seems like another reasonable approach for dealing with vague answers ("weakening" this bad attitude).

Comment: @Omega downvoted answers remain visible, and anyone can upvote them back. And single answer upvote recovers rep lost from 5 (_five_) downvotes. And voting ansers down costs voter reputation. And... I find it hard to believe that you aren't aware of how that system works after almost 3 years spent at Programmers and Stack Overflow

Comment: @gnat: What does rep have to do with it?  If I had an answer with 4 downvotes and 1 upvote, that would bother me a lot, and the 2 rep "profit" wouldn't make up for it.  The answer would also be greyed out and sorted to the bottom of the pile.  How exactly is that not a punishment?  Also, the rep penalty is a measly 1 point.

Comment: @gnat: Oh, I interpreted the greyed out answers as invisible for newcomers. Anyway, I would be rather concerned if I had multiple downvotes, and that would likely change my attitude, regardless of how little rep I lose. If it affects my attitude, then it is a good measure to downvote the vague answers, I'd think.

Comment: @gnat: On a side note, my lack of meta-knowledge might be because I never had meta-issues before. I spent ~3 years here, but not learning meta stuff, but rather, learning programming stuff.

Comment: @MichaelShaw you see, even your example takes 4 downvoters (against single voter up) to make it _bothersome_. -1 penalty may mean little to you and to me, but to most users, it feels sensitive (that's by design) - making it naturally harder to find 4 downvoters as in your example. Now imagine a question having 4-5 low quality answers (typical count for naming games). Now imagine 3-5 such questions posted a week (here, we discuss the case to declare these legal and worth keeping open, don't we)...

Comment: @gnat: I based my example on your example.  I don't think it takes 4 downvotes to get someone's attention.  I've got an answer with 17 upvotes and 1 downvote, and the one downvote bothered me.  I'm not sure what you're getting at with the rest of the comment.  There are 3 answers to Omega's question, with no negative scores for any answer.  There are only 2 downvotes on the answers, and neither downvoter even bothered to leave a comment.  All of the answers were by someone with > 3K rep.  Imagining 3-5 such questions a week is not scary.

Comment: @MichaelShaw Omega's question is not typical, because it missed a chance to reach wide exposure (through "hot questions") due to downvotes and closure. Examples of naming game questions that weren't closed in time are [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/124176) (3 answers deleted), [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/62570) (2 answers deleted), [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/141420/31260) (2 answers deleted) - feel free to waste your rep / voting limit on voting down tons of low quality crap collected in these

Comment: @gnat It also looks like none of them ever had the "protected" status.

Comment: @Omega how about you first test yourself what you are suggesting? One of the answers to your question ("bindings...") reads like a guesswork [by your own definition here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6296/why-is-this-question-wrong-asking-for-the-name-of-a-specific-practice/6298?noredirect=1#comment17085_6297 "'Type Aliasing perfectly fits my description with no loose ends'"): try what you feel should work there and then tell us how it works

Comment: @Izkata protecting questions has pretty specific purpose ([documented eg in this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78762/165773)); worth noting that protecting questions "just because" these are naming games hardly fits that purpose

Comment: @gnat No, you'd protect it "just because" its getting lots of low-quality pseudo-answers due to extensive exposure by way of the Hot Questions list.  Many of those bad answers are by low-rep users - unfortunately, it's hard to tell now how many of them would've been below that threshold back when the answer was posted.

Comment: @Izkata that makes sense, protection not before, but _after_ damage is done and proven. For naming game questions, such a damage is the case way too often, which makes me prefer closure

Comment: @gnat: I don't think when the questions were closed had anything to do with it.  One of the questions you refer to was asking for the name of a construction with a lot of parts, and it would make sense for it not to have (or need) a name.  The other two said "here's a name for something, tell me another name for it".  Omega's question, on the other hand, was specific, had a practical point, and was much lengthier than the others (one was only 3 sentences).  The problem with your three examples is not that they weren't closed on time.

Comment: @MichaelShaw as far as I can tell, nothing in the question prevented a useless guesswork answer (which additionally got a sympathy upvote) - in that sense, I see no difference between it and 3 examples I referred

Comment: @gnat: I don't think it is the job of a question to prevent bad answers.  Among other reasons, they can't actually do that.  You may think that the reason for the upvote was sympathy, but that is your presumption.  Neither the upvoter nor the downvoter left a comment.  If you honestly can't see how this question is different from the others (none of which were reopened, BTW) then I don't think this conversation is going to get anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelShaw prevention of bad answers isn't possible at all, at least in SE Q&A model; job of the question is to avoid _inviting_ these ([Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)). Naming games invite guesswork answers

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any votes on this question, so this is more just me going "hmm..." with some various thoughts on the matter.

An important thing to realize is that questions have been asked in the past and are currently open is not an indication that something that is asked in the same or similar format will also be covered as "older stuff is open too".  There is a lot of old questions that are not good examples of questions to ask.

I would also strongly suggest steering away from the "but it was answered" as an indication to question.  From a previous issue ( [Closed as not constructive?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5563/closed-as-not-constructive/) ) the argument was made:

> The only answer given (likely before it was closed) clearly suggests that the question is constructive.

The reason to close such a question is that it has the likelihood of blowing up to everyone adding their own two cents to the question.  I would suggest looking at your example of [Vocabulary: Should I call this apply or map?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171430/vocabulary-should-i-call-this-apply-or-map) which has answers such as:

> You could call it an n-dimensional pointwise Cartesian product of functions. However, that doesn't make for a short name, and might require explanation...

.

> I'd call it fire_callbacks, call_callbacks, apply_callbacks, or something like that.
>
> I've usually had such a method as part of a signal or observable object.

.

> To my mind, the word "map" implies some kind of association (e.g. a 'dictionary'), although there doesn't appear to be any association or pairing of data happening in your algorithm.

Everyone has their own opinion about how things are called, even if there is a real name for it.

This question is strongly related to the post [Are "name that thing" questions on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/are-name-that-thing-questions-on-topic) which has a variety of opinions on the topic.  A more recent meta post seeking a more updated clarification can be read at [Is asking "what is the technical term for this" on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6089/is-asking-what-is-the-technical-term-for-this-on-topic)

From this more recent question there are two opinions, one of which can be recapped as:

> These kinds of questions essentially boil down to "what terms should I Google for?" They are an indirect proxy for resource requests, which are specifically off-topic.

The key issue with the "find the name" is that we really don't want (and this is a community consensus thing more than a formal policy) to become [ELU single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests).

The questions of the 'name that thing' are without end - they are localized to *your* usage and situation and tend not to be something that generates long term useful content.

A poor metric (I know) of that "long term useful content" might be in part driven from views.  If you look at your example questions, no matter how old they are they all have about 300-400 views. This suggests that they got them at the initial date of creation and then no one looked at them again.  I know that thats a *very* poor qualification because some of the more esoteric questions have even fewer views (I mean... who wants to read about haskell monads?) but are likely good long term material.

So...

Thats all about my thoughts on the subject and bringing together some other posts to consider when looking into why it was closed.  The "Name that thing" is a touchy area because of the possibility that it brings in lots of people saying "I call it `this` in my shop" and others saying "I call it `that` where I work."

---

As to the "called something else in each language..."

> The question asks, essentially, how is it called when you create constants that refer to large namespaces in an attempt to simplify the writing. Basically, something like:
>
> `Sprite = Super::Large:Namespace::Graphics::Sprite`

Well, in perl, this is a [typeglob](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) alias (what are types?) (not to be confused with [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)s)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Foo::Bar::Qux::Bletch;

$var = 42;

package main;

print $Foo::Bar::Qux::Bletch::var, "\n";

*A = *Foo::Bar::Qux::Bletch::var;

print $A,"\n";
```

Or at least... thats what I call it.  Though some people may call it [symbol table aliasing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables) which wouldn't really be wrong either.  And apparently some call it [glob aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14071422/289086) too.  Oh well.

Comment: Although the site has a very different focus, over on SciFi.SE we ask to include links to references and will delete the answers without them.  Perhaps something similar is a good idea here.  No need to punish the question/type of question if there _is_ a well-known name for it.  (I had thought something like that was already in practice here, honestly, but since apparently "I call it `that` where I work." is a concern, I guess not?) (And don't hold back the downvotes!  Downvote those into oblivion anyway, since they _are_ bad answers!)

Comment: @Izkata [Apple.SE] allows for "List of X" type questions - [Please share your hidden OS X features or tips and tricks](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/) that get deleted quickly on P.SE and SO. Math.SE encourages homework questions with no work. [cstheory.se] and MathOverflow won't even consider your question unless you are doing graduate level research. NetworkEngineering.SE will only consider questions about enterprise networking (home networking is off topic). SciFi allows "what is that story...?" and Gaming.SE only allows it if there are screen shots.

Comment: @Izkata what I'm trying to get at there is that each SE site is different and the community allows (and doesn't allow) certain things. "Name that thing" has had some difficulties in the past - [What is each time through a loop called?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/95920/), [What kind of bug is this?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/74022/), [What do you call this pattern/technique?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/89012/), [What do you call one element in an enumeration?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/57095/) and so on.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of open questions in the "what do you call" set that people haven't gotten around to closing. People have just gotten to really not liking them. There is a large amount of jargon in programming, and people polling for "what do you call" for every thing they think of (surely, it must have a well recognized term...) [became difficult to handle](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+do+you+call%22+is%3Aquestion) (very small subset - just one phrase of many people use) and rather tedious. Close votes reflect that legacy.

Comment: It might be worth noting that I'm not asking what do *you* call it. Some of those questions have actual standard answers (Type Aliasing, Maps, Arrays, Extract), whereas others are indeed pure guesswork. My question does have an "actual answer" so to speak, for Type Aliasing perfectly fits my description with no loose ends. Not that this changes your points though.

Comment: @Izkata I for one am rather opposed to this criteria at Programmers. Not because it's generally bad mind you, but because it's not uniform and doesn't match well to "conceptual" questions (a more appropriate criteria for which would be to require explanation). To have a type of questions that differs from the rest by an additional criteria "links to references + delete the answers without them" would make site more complicated for users, even though criteria is good per se. As another example, we don't require code (here we differ from SO), even though some (not all) questions need it

Comment: A more practical problem is that even things that feel like they *should* have one name, usually have more than one, and often for good reason. For example, `map` is called `project` in Relational Algebra, `SELECT` in SQL (and consequently `Select` in .NET), `transform` in C++, `collect:` in Smalltalk (and consequently Self, Newspeak and Ruby) and so on. `fold` is often called `reduce` (`inject:into:` in Smalltalk, `inject` in Ruby, `accumulate` in C++, `AGGREGATE` in SQL and consequently `Aggregate` in .NET), and in some languages `fold` and `reduce` actually mean different things.

Comment: So, even if you take great care to *not* ask for a list, you'll probably get one anyway.

Comment: @JörgWMittag updated the answer to include a specific 'another name' for another language for the example.